# How to hide the data table that gets shown while plotting subplots using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am plotting 4 x 4 subplots using matplotlib using the code below.The subplots are generated, but the data used for them is so large that the data table gets overlapped with the plot figure. Check the link below to see an image of the problem. Any idea how to resolve this issue?

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(4,4)
f.suptitle('Sharing X axis')

B = [10, 20, 30, 40]
M1 = [sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4]
M2 = [avg1, avg2, avg3, avg4]

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        scatter_method = M1[j]
        line_method = M2[j]
        budget = B[i]
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(scatter_method)
        scatter_data = df1.loc[df1.Budget == budget]
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(line_method)
        line_data = df2.loc[df2.Budget == budget]
        axarr[i, j].scatter(scatter_data['Sample_Size'], scatter_data['Samples'], marker = ".", c='y')
        axarr[i, j].plot(line_data['Sample_Size'], line_data['Sample_Avg'], marker = ".", c='b')
        axarr[i,j].set_title(scatter_method)
        axarr[i, j].set_axisbelow(True)
        axarr[i, j].grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5', color='red')
        axarr[i, j].minorticks_on()
        axarr[i, j].grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.5', color='black')

f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.3, wspace=0.3)        
plt.show()
```

This image shows how the output looks like:

[image: This image shows how the output looks like]

Comment: Assuming the xdata is the same, did you try the argument sharex ='all' in subplots?  Additionally can you share some mockdata for me to edit the code.

Comment: Please remove the line `axarr[i,j].set_title(scatter_method)` from your code. Then, if the output is unexpected or undesired, show the new image created by the code without that line and clearly explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks GlobalTraveler and ImportanceOfBeingErnest for your suggestions. The sharex='all' did not had any effect. However, removing axarr[i,j].set_title(scatter_method) from the code did the work. Thanks again.